# C# substract 2 strings without getting negatives

Tags: c#

i need some help with my code.
i've got to make a math game with subtracting without getting negatives but my code doesn't seem to work.

```
int c = a - b;
if (c < 0)
{
    Random ro = new Random();
    a = ro.Next(10) + 1;
    b = ro.Next(10) + 1;
    lb_getal1.Text = a.ToString();
    lb_getal2.Text = b.ToString();
}
if (txt_antwoord.Text == c.ToString())
{
    MessageBox.Show("You provided the right answer!");
    score += 1;

    Random r = new Random();
    a = r.Next(10) + 1;
    b = r.Next(10) + 1;
    lb_getal1.Text = a.ToString();
    lb_getal2.Text = b.ToString();
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("You were wrong!");
}
if (score == 5)
{
    MessageBox.Show("You answered 5 answers correctly! Well done!");
    this.Close();
    RM_menu form = new RM_menu();
    form.Show();
}
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work as expected?

Comment: Please use English string while posting your code. Others won't understand the localised string.

Comment: Edit your question and add expected behaviour and what does not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems in your code. The first thing to improve is: use only one instance of `Random`.

The `Random` class provides *pseudo* random numbers from a list. If you create an instance with the default constructor `new Random()`, the instance is initialized with a seed taken from the current time. Since there is not much time between your two calls, both instances probably use the same seed and you will get the same values for `a` and `b` again.
I suggest to create only one instance and store it in a member variable of your class.

Second problem: if your first try results in a negative `c`, you only try again once, but that does not make sure that this time it will be positive. A better approach is to compare `a` and `b` and switch if `b` is larger.

So the your code could look like this:

```
public class YourGame : Form // I guess it's a Form
{
    private Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    private int a;
    private int b;
    private int score;

    public void CreateQuestion()
    {
        a = randomGenerator.Next(10) + 1;
        b = randomGenerator .Next(10) + 1;
        if (b > a)
        {
            // switch values
            int tmp = b;
            b = a;
            a = tmp;
        }

        lb_getal1.Text = a.ToString();
        lb_getal2.Text = b.ToString();            
    }

    private void OnAnswer()
    {
        int c = a - b; // will never be negative as we checked a and b above
        if (txt_antwoord.Text == c.ToString())
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You provided the right answer!");
            score += 1;
            CreateQuestion();
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("You were wrong!");

        if (score == 5)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You answered 5 answers correctly! Well done!");
            this.Close();
            RM_menu form = new RM_menu();
            form.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: nice answer to a sloppy question.

Comment: @Natrium there are days when I simply vote to close, and then there are days when I think "hey, it's obvious, let's help"...

Answer (score 1):

I am not trying to solve this problem, but trying to give some inputs on how to make sure that the value would not be less than zero when using `Random`.

```
int a, b, c;
Random ro;

ro = new Random();
b = ro.Next(10);
a = ro.Next(b, 10);
c = a - b;
```

As you can see, first we set a random value to `b` using `ro.Next(10)` and then we specify a minimum value by using `ro.Next(b, 10)`

Doing so, it is guaranteed that the value would not be less than zero when doing `a-b`.

Comment: Nice idea to use this `Next` overload.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Math.Abs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.abs(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
int c = Math.Abs (a-b);
```

Comment: How does that solve the issue? No... What issue you actually think you were solving?

Comment: so this guy has 2 numbers, and he doesnt want to subtract it in a way that would give him the negative answer, so he probably even wanted to swap those numbers, as Rene has in his code. So i simply suggested the Absolute function, so you wont have to check for negative or that the variable on the left of the subtraction should be greater. You think that doesnt answer the question? cuz the question is vague anyway, he gets the full answer or not, he should have the knowledge that Abs function exists.

Comment: both your answer and your comment do make sense, but I still have no idea what the exact problem is the OP is facing.